# Min no. of lines to cover (2n)x(2n) grid of dots

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in the number of straight lines (not horizontal or vertical) required that cover all dots in a grid of $(2n)\times(2n)$ dots where $n>0$. It feels like the best you can do is $4n-2$, just picking lines that cover the most dots every time (so to demonstrate you would start with covering the 2 diagonals first) but I cannot seem to put together a proof. Any hints would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint

Your conjectured formula is correct. To prove this, consider the task of covering the points on the outside border only. How many points are on the outside border? How many points can each line cover?

#### Solution

> There are $4\times (2n-1)$ points on the outside border of the $2n\times 2n$ grid. Because horizontal and vertical lines are not allowed, each line can only cover two border points; one point when the line enters the square, and one point where the line exits the square. Therefore, in order to cover all of the border points, the number of lines required is $\frac{8n-4}{2}=4n-2$.
>
>  This is attainable. First, use one of the main diagonal lines, with a slope of $+1$. Then, for each point on the north and west border, use a line through that point with a slope of $-1$. This covers all points.

Comment: Thanks, the hints were perfect! I think this reasoning would generalise to nxn grids right, where n can be odd? So would just be 2n-2 in general?

Comment: @niceriemann Yes :^)